# Hecke Operators

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, modular-forms

I'm currently working my way through the section on Hecke operators in Serre's book. In the proof that $ T(m)T(n) = T(mn) $ for all $ m,n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} $ with $ \textit{gcd}(m,n) = 1 $.

In this proof Serre makes the claim that a group $ \Gamma/\Gamma'' $ of order $ mn $ decomposes uniquely into a direct sum of a group of order $ m $ and a group of order $ n $. He attributes this to something called $ \textit{Bezout's theorem} $.

I have googled $ \textit{Bezout's theorem} $ and can't seem to find anything that can imply this claim. In particular I can't see why $ \Gamma/\Gamma'' $ cannot be the direct sum  of two groups of orders $ m' $ and $ n' $ such that $ m'n' = mn $. If someone could explain why this cannot be the case, or point me towards the correct theorem I would be most greatful.

Comment: 1) Likely this is referring to a form of Bezout's identity rather than Bezout's theorem.  2) Why can't both be true?

Comment: Yea I had a look a Bezout's identity, I can't see anything in that which could imply the above case.

Comment: With regards to why can't both be true, I managed to prove that subgroups of $ \Gamma $ correspond to subgroups of $ \mathbb{Z}^{2} $. At this point we start to rely on my rather rusty group theory, I believe the subgroups of $ \mathbb{Z}^{2} $ which give a quotient group of index $ mn $ are the subgroups of the from $ m'\mathbb{Z} \times n'\mathbb{Z} $ where $ m'n' = mn $.

Comment: Serre says "the" group $\Gamma/\Gamma''$ decomposes in a certain way, which is different from what you have written in your question.

Comment: Yea but what I'm trying to find out is how Serre knows this. He attributes it to Bezout's theorem, but I can't see how that explains it. I am not suggesting that Serre is wrong.

Comment: This follows from structure theory of f.g. abelian groups. And for example if $m=15, n=14$, $m'=10$, $n'=21$ we have these isomorphisms like
$$C_m\times C_n\cong C_{m'}\times C_{n'}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite abelian group $G$ can be uniquely written as a direct sum of its prime power torsion parts:
$$
G=\bigoplus_pG_p,
$$
where for each prime $p$ we have
$$
G_p=\{x\in G\mid p^mx=0\,\text{for some natural number $m$}\}.
$$
The $m$-part then simply collects those $G_p$ that $p\mid m$. Ditto for the $n$-part.

---

This is the first time I hear about this being called Bezout's theorem. Frenchmen?

Comment: Yea I think Serre is French. Again thank you for your help also. It is much appreciated and I'm going to have a good look over these. Out of interest are you aware of the result you have described going under another name?

Comment: I have always referred to this as part of the structure theorem of f.g. abelian groups. It does take many forms :-)

Comment: Ah I remember briefly looking at the structure theorem at the end of a group theory course 2 years back. Time for a serious revision by the sounds of it.